# Jquery not working on button click

Tags: jquery, django

I am sending an ajax request to my server using Jquery. But my code doesn't sense the button click. My code seems to be fine. I don't know where I am going wrong. I am using Django template engine. I included the jquery **script** in my script block. In order check whether my button click is sensed I used an alert in button click event handler. But I did not get alert message.

**My code:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock script %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 2%;padding-top:1%;">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h2>BookMyHotel</h2>
        </div>

        {% if name %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="{% url 'admin' %}" > {{ name }}</a> |
                <a href="{% url 'office_logout' %}" class="btn btn-primary" >Log out</a><br/><br/>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 4%">
        <form  class="form-group" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" style="padding-top: 1%" action = "{% url 'update_employee' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>Update employee</h3>
            {% if message %}
                <b id="message" style="color: red">{{ message }}</b>
            {% endif %}
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Hotel id</label>
                <label id="hotel_id" class="control-label">bmh-{{ hotel_id }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Hotel name</label>
                <label id="hotel_name" class="control-label">{{ hotel_name }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Employee ID</label>
                <input class="form-control col-sm-2" type="text" id="employee_id" name = "employee_id" placeholder = "Employee ID" required="true" >
                <input type = "button" id="check" value = "Check" class="btn btn-primary">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Designation</label>
                <input class="form-control col-sm-2" type="text" id="designation" name = "designation" placeholder = "Designation" required="true" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Experience</label>
                <input class="form-control col-sm-2" type="text" id="experience" name = "experience" placeholder = "Experience" required="true" >
            </div>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Create" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>

    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#check').on('click', function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    var id = $('#employee_id').val();
                    alert(id);
                    var data = {'employee_id': id};
                    $.ajax({

                        url: {% url 'update_employee' %},
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                           if(data.msg == 'success'){
                                $('#update_sec').show();


                                $('#designation').val(data.designation);
                                $('#experience').val(data.experience);


                           }
                           else{

                               $('#message').text("Employee does not exist.");
                           }
                        }

                    });
                });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: any errors in browser console ?

Comment: Are you sure that the jquery is applied applied at all? Try using console.log('Hello World!') and see if this gets printed in the browser console when you click the button. The reason I'm asking is because I dunno where the two blocks lead to. To be sure you could put the script src part in the header of base.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use "onclick".

```
<input type = "button" id="check" value = "Check" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myfunction()">
```

and

```
<script>
        function myfunction() {
                    alert('hi');
                    var id = $('#employee_id').val();
                    alert(id);
                    var data = {'employee_id': id};
                    $.ajax({

                        url: {% url 'update_employee' %},
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                           if(data.msg == 'success'){
                                $('#update_sec').show();


                                $('#designation').val(data.designation);
                                $('#experience').val(data.experience);


                           }
                           else{

                               $('#message').text("Employee does not exist.");
                           }
                        }

                    });
                }
    </script>
```